# Yup: How i can make a conditional rule?

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm trying to make a conditional rule with Yup, but I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: ref must be a string, got: true if (typeof key !==
>   'string') throw new TypeError('ref must be a string, got: ' + key);
>        | ^  17 | this.key = key.trim();   18 | if (key === '') throw new TypeError('ref must be a non-empty string');   19 | this.isContext =
>   this.key[0] === prefixes.context;

This is what I've tried:

```
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        login: Yup.string()
            .email('Email dont valid')
            .required('Fill the email!'),
        password: Yup.string().required('You need to fill the password').when(user.hasOwnProperty('id'), {
            is: false
        }),
    })
```

When my object user doesn't have the property `id`, the password is `required`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `.email('Email don't valid')` is going to generate invalid javascript. Are you sure that's what's in your code?

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica sorry i translated the words when i'm writing this post and i forget this, i fix this in question, thanks